# Using KIImagePager with external images loads each time the view scrolls

Tags: ios, objective-c, parallax

I'm using QMBParallaxScrollViewController with KIImagePager in its top. Each time I scroll it, the KIImagePager loads all the images each time.

This is the code I have in the top bar

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.photos = [NSMutableArray array];

    for(NSString* imageURL in self.pictures) {
        [self.photos addObject: [ENDPOINT stringByAppendingString: imageURL]];
    }

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSArray *) arrayWithImages
{

    return self.photos;
}

- (UIViewContentMode) contentModeForImage:(NSUInteger)image
{
    return UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
}
```

The methods that are triggered are arrayWithImages and contentModeForImage.

How can I change this behavior?

Comment: Any update on this Carlos? I'm running into the same issue..

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's okay if viewcontroller triggers `arrayWithImages` method frequently. The `self.photos` array get filled once on viewcontroller's loading, thereby it doesn't affect performance. It's a usual pattern on iOS to ask the method for data, not the property. The only thing which should be considered is that method should return data as fast as possible. `arrayWithImages` returns `self.photos`, therefore it should work without any issues on performance.

To prevent reloading of images, use `NSURLCache`. Add this to your app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
  NSURLCache *URLCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:4 * 1024 * 1024 
                                                       diskCapacity:20 * 1024 * 1024 
                                                           diskPath:nil];
  [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:URLCache];
}
```

If you need to learn more about `NSURLCache`, take a look at this awesome article http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache

Comment: yeah, but I have images loaded from an url, so each time I scroll, the images load again. That's the problem

Comment: Use `NSURLCache` to prevent re-loading of the image.

Comment: actually, I'm using iOS 7, so it should do automatically this, right? But still have this problem. What I see is that only in the scroll this happen. Cause this is a parallax control, in changes the size dinamically. I guess this is the reason kiimagepager want to reload the image.

Also, I know they work with SDWebImage. It supposed to generate cache.